# Click on button while pressing Enter

Tags: javascript, html, algolia

I use for my current online store, the search of Algolia. I would like to extend this search with the function that when customers press the Enter key, the click on the button "Show all results" is triggered.

My problem is that I constantly get the error message (

> index):TypeError: input.addEventListener is not a
> function

in the devtools and I slowly do not know why. Anyone have an idea how I can trigger this click event?

**HTML Input**

```
<input class="ais-SearchBox-input" type="search" placeholder="" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" maxlength="512">
```

HTML Button

```
<a class="search-query-route cta-button w-inline-block" id="milo" style="margin-top:-20px" href="">Alle Ergebnisse anzeigen</a>
```

**Script**

```
var input = document.getElementsByClassName(".");
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    event.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("milo").click();
  }
});
```

Comment: Normally you do that sort of thing using a form, you then and make a button a type submit.

Comment: You're getting the error cause you're missing the class on input should look like this `var input = document.getElementsByClassName("ais-SearchBox-input");`

Answer (score 1):

This is because addEventListener is a function on HTMLElement.  since you are using the var `input` and `input` is the result of a get**Elements**ByClassName call, you do not have an HTMLElement.  you have an array of HTMLElements.  Even if it is only one. You can fix this by putting an ID on the element (which is good practice anyway, and then using the GetElementByID function to set your var `input`.

```js
var input = document.getElementById("myField");
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    event.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("milo").click();
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="myField" class="ais-SearchBox-input" type="search" placeholder="" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" maxlength="512">

<a class="search-query-route cta-button w-inline-block" id="milo" style="margin-top:-20px" href="">Alle Ergebnisse anzeigen</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an ID attribute on the HTML input control so you can find it easily. So change

```
<input class="ais-SearchBox-input" type="search" placeholder="" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" maxlength="512">
```

to

```
<input id="myspecialinput" class="ais-SearchBox-input" type="search" placeholder="" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" maxlength="512">
```

Then change the code that wires up the event handler from

```
var input = document.getElementsByClassName(".");
```

to

```
var input = document.getElementById("myspecialinput");
```

Comment: Wouldn't they be able to find the element with a class name too?

Comment: Not when the class name you are searching with is ".". Maybe you were thinking that a single period would act like a wildcard or something. It does not. It will not find anything.

Comment: What! No.  I thought you'd mention that using `getElementByClassName` returns an array as opposed to using `getElementById` which returns just that specific element. I asked that just so you could explain it this way, cos chances are the questioner doesn't know this and it's best to clarify why they should use `getElementById` instead of `getElementsByClassName`.

Comment: According to the DOM specification, no 2 DOM elements can have the same ID, so getElementById will only ever find 0 or 1 DOM elements, which makes it deterministic. As Fortune explained, getElementsByClassName returns an array, which is a non-deterministic result, so unless there is a compelling reason (such as assigning a handler to a bunch of related elements) to find your elements using a class name, always use the ID to find them. It is good practice to ensure that all of the DOM elements that you want to work with programmatically have a unique ID attribute.

Comment: Good one! Now they know why they should use getElementById

Answer (score 0):

You're missing your class name

Change this

```js
var input = document.getElementsByClassName(".");
```

to this

```js
var input = document.getElementsByClassName("ais-SearchBox-input")[0];
```